# AtTask API only returns a subset of the fields on an object

Tags: java, json, api, rest, attask

When I use the `/search` or the `&method=get` on a company (and other objects), I only get a subset of the fields in return.  How do I get all of the fields?

i.e.

```
https://example.com/attask/api/company?id=52cc12f0000b053291be85eb0fb10da0&method=get
```

returns:

```
{"data":{"ID":"52cc12f0000b053291be85eb0fb10da0","name":"SomeCompany","objCode":"CMPY","hasNotes":false,"notes":null,"lastNote":null,"lastNoteID":null}}
```

But the Company object also has (from the API Docs):
--SNIP--

> categoryID
>   API Key: categoryID
>   Field Type: string
>   
>   customerID
>   API Key: customerID
>   Field Type: string
>   
>   enteredByID
>   API Key: enteredByID
>   Field Type: string
>   
>   entryDate
>   API Key: entryDate
>   Field Type: dateTime
>   
>   extRefID
>   API Key: extRefID
>   Field Type: string
>   
>   hasRateOverride
>   API Key: hasRateOverride
>   Field Type: boolean
>   
>   lastUpdateDate
>   API Key: lastUpdateDate
>   Field Type: dateTime
>   
>   lastUpdatedByID
>   API Key: lastUpdatedByID
>   Field Type: string

--/SNIP--
How do I get these Fields to return when I request the object?

Please NOTE:  I am also working on a Java Project to learn the API.  I have downloaded and am using the JAVA API examples from the community site, so I'm hoping your answer will also apply there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AtTask uses lazy loading of return fields with only a small subset of fields returned by default. You can specify which fields you want in your result by passing a comma-separated list of field names as the fields parameter like this:

```
https://mydomain.com/attask/api/company?id=52cc12f0000b053291be85eb0fb10da0&method=get&fields=name,entryDate
```

Which will return the name and entryDate of the company record.

Comment: I was hoping they had a "return all" but couldn't find anything like that in the docs.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following you will get all fields

```
&method=get&fields=*
```